# Why does the variance of a type parameter affect the time at which an illegal cast of its nested type parameter is caught?

Tags: c#, casting, runtime-error, covariance

With the following class structure:

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}
interface Cov<out T> {
}
class Inv<T> : Cov<T> {}
```

Somewhat to my surprise, the following cast compiles without error, but throws an `InvalidCastException` at runtime:

```
Cov<Inv<Base>> v = (Cov<Inv<Base>>)(new Inv<Inv<Derived>>());
```

The covariance is apparently crucial, since replacing the outer `Cov` with `Inv` as so:

```
Inv<Inv<Base>> v = (Inv<Inv<Base>>)(new Inv<Inv<Derived>>());
```

issues a compiler error as expected:

> Error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ParameterCast.Inv<ParameterCast.Inv<ParameterCast.Derived>>' to 'ParameterCast.Inv<ParameterCast.Inv<ParameterCast.Base>>'

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: In theory, the compiler only knows that type `Inv<Int<Derived>>` is an upper bound. That it is actually that type is something you know. There could be a subclass of `Int<T>` that implements the interface `Cov<Int<Base>>`, in which case the cast succeeds at runtime. In the other case it knows that the concrete type `Int<Int<Derived>>`  could never be an upper bound for the concrete type `Int<Int<Base>>`. It's not variance but whether the type is an interface that affects the outcome.

Comment: @mikez I see that now, with changing `Cov` to a class resulting in a compile-time error. I can also understand the cast succeeding if `Inv<Inv<Derived>>` implemented `Cov<Inv<Base>>`, but since it doesn't in this case, what remains unknown to the compiler? How can a subclass of `Inv<Tu>` that implements `Cov<Tv>` exist, for Tu≠Tv? So far as I understand, wouldn't any `Cov` methods would be duplicated with different types?